# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout

Tags: java, ant, log4j

I'm trying to build an application using ant. Everything appears to be fine when I build but I continually get the above error for what I've tried so far.

- `java -jar dist/pmml_export.jar`
- `java -cp ".:log4j-1.2.16.jar" -jar dist/pmml_export.jar`
- `java -cp log4j-1.2.16.jar -jar dist/pmml_export.jar`

I doubled checked to see if Layout was in the jar I'm referencing and it is there. I'm fairly new to both ant and log4j so I could be making an obvious mistake but I'm just not seeing it. Here is my `build.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="pmml_export" default="archive">

  <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
  </target>

  <path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="build/classes" includes="*.class" />
  </path>

  <property name="ant.dir" value="apache-log4j-1.2.16"/>

  <path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${ant.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
  </path>

  <target name="exceptions" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="src/exceptions" destdir="build/classes" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
    <echo> Exceptions compiled! </echo>
  </target>

  <target name="symbol-table" depends="exceptions" >
    <javac srcdir="src/translator/symbol_table" destdir="build/classes"   classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
    <echo> Symbol table compiled! </echo>
  </target>

  <target name="parser" depends="symbol-table" >
    <javac srcdir="src/translator/parser" destdir="build/classes" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
    <echo> Parser compiled! </echo>
  </target>

  <target name="lexer" depends="parser" >
    <javac srcdir="src/translator/lexer" destdir="build/classes"  classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
    <echo> Lexer compiled! </echo>
  </target>

  <target name="translator" depends="lexer" >
    <javac srcdir="src/translator" destdir="build/classes" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
    <echo> Translator compiled! </echo>
  </target>

  <target name="exporter" depends="translator" >
    <javac srcdir="src/pmml_export" destdir="build/classes" classpathref="compile.classpath" />
    <echo> Exporter compiled! </echo>
  </target>

  <target name="archive" depends="exporter" >
    <property name="manifest.mf" location="dist/manifest.txt" />
    <manifest file="${manifest.mf}" >
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="pmml_export.PMML_Export"/>
    </manifest>
    <jar destfile="dist/pmml_export.jar" manifest="${manifest.mf}"
  basedir="build/classes" />
  </target>

  <target name="run" depends="archive">
    <java jar="dist/pmml_exporter.jar" fork="true">
      <classpath>
        <path refid="classpath"/>
        <path location="dist/pmml_exporter.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </java>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: The `-cp` argument is **ignored** when using the `-jar` argument. You need to tell Ant to specify the classpath as `Class-Path` entry of JAR's `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: What OS? On Windows -cp a.jar;b.jar

Comment: @Op De Cirkel: The OS is Ubuntu 10.04 and I'm running it on a VM Player. The host OS is Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `-jar` option, the `-cp` and `-classpath` options are ignored.  The proper way to embed the classpath with the `-jar` option is to set a Class-Path directive in the jar's `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: That fixed it. I added this line here to the manifest spec:                                                                  <attribute name="Class-Path" value="apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar" />
Thanks Edwin

Comment: @Erik, glad to hear about the success.  You're welcome, anytime.